# Can't connect to mysql aws RDS - 10060 odbc logged error

Tags: mysql, odbc, amazon-rds, network-security, superuser

I'm trying to debug an ODBC connection failing to a MySQL instance on aws rds.  The connection works on all but a single machine. This machine is connected to large financial systems network, so I assume it would be the firewall.

So far, I've..

- made rds instance public accessable
- whitelisted the machine's IP
- had their network folks open port 3306 on machine.
- network folks confirmed data is going out port 3306, but nothing is coming back.
- traced on machine's odbc log...10060 error (usually inbound rule to RDS error..)
- opened ALL inbound to RDS to accept from all (0.0.0.0/0 ) - still get error
- setup the RDS instance error log, but doesn't record these failed connects. It seems to only log if it is a user/password fail..?

my questions:

- is there an aws rds log that would show these failed attempts?
- does windows firewall on port 3306 also need an inbound rule? Or does opening it assume inbound/outbound?

Again - all the other machines are able to access the rds mysql fine. Only this one can not connect - and i am sure it's very protected, due to its access to major financial systems.

any ideas what else I can try?

thanks!

Comment: Are you connecting to the RDS from outside of AWS? If so, have you enable public accessability for it?

Comment: Yes, public accessable - i'm accessing from other machines fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe the issue is that on firewall setup, they are allowing incoming on 3306 **only** if its a secured connection (using ipSec I believe).
i'll likely need to look into a vpn to connect to AWS rds.

Answer (score 0):

On your security group you will need to enable for public access (or just your IP), and sometimes it can take a long time to apply these changes, for me it took 5 hours once upon ago;

Comment: yes, had made it public, and getting at it from different ip addresses fine. just not from this machine with stricter firewall i'd imagine